# Using laravel controllers as components to build a view

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5

I have various components that will go into my Laravel 5.4 app, and each page is built using these components. Each component will have its own logic, making API calls (which will be cached), etc.

Each component controller returns a view after working through its logic.

Here is an example controller:

```
class ExampleController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $projects = Api::create()->get('project/1234')
        return View::make('Pages::components.projectList')
            ->with('projects', self::$projects);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is create a "master" controller for each page that will bring the various components together.

Something like:

`return ExampleController@index . OtherController@index`

Later on, I want users to be able to build their own pages using these components, so building static views won't work. The component controllers will *always* return a view.

How is this done in Laravel? Am I thinking about the problem all wrong?

Comment: You can do that. But that is not what I will suggest you do. 
If I understand you correctly, you want to build components of a page with Controllers and you want to merge the partial views to make a complete view. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I can suggest you a better architecture. If I am wrong, please let me know where I am falling.

Comment: That is correct. The partial views are built by their own controllers and I want to merge them to make a complete view. What would be a better architecture?

Comment: You can use You can use **view composers**: https://laravel-news.com/introducing-view-components-on-laravel-an-alternative-to-view-composers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging in the Laravel docs, it seems that this is a clean way to do it:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $projectList = (new ProjectListController())->index();
        $searchBox = (new SearchBoxController())->index();

        return view("App::index")
            ->with('projectList', $projectList)
            ->with('searchBox', $searchBox);
    }
}
```

The index method is the primary method of the controller that returns the view.

For this to work, each component controller needs to return only an HTML view, but this has worked cleanly in my app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[view composers](https://laravel-news.com/introducing-view-components-on-laravel-an-alternative-to-view-composers)**.

Example to pass `highlights` to every view:

```
<?php

class HighLightsComposer
{

    protected $users;

    public function __construct(BlogRepository $blog)
    {
        $this->blog = $blog
    }

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('highlights', $this->blog->highlights());
    }
}

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer(
            'highlights', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\HighlighsComposer'
        );
    }
}

class HomeController extends Controller {

    protected $blog;

    public function __construct(BlogRepository $blog)
    {
        $this->blog = $blog
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('blog', [
            'posts' => $blog->latest()
        ]);
    }
}

class ContactPageController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        return view('contact');
    }

}
```

Ref: https://laravel-news.com/introducing-view-components-on-laravel-an-alternative-to-view-composers

Answer (score 0):

I will be using Laravel 5.3 to refer for this architecture.  You need to distribute the data into following things:

1. View (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views)
2. Models (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent)
3. Controllers (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers)
4. Blade Templating (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade)

What you are doing is you are appending the views itself. Using this logic, you would not be able to figure out of your HTML inside your view is breaking until and unless it is rendered. Instead, use blade templating for views. Refer "Extending A Layout" in Blade templating to understand how to join the views. 
Secondly, now to get and pass data, use models through controllers.

So, for example, let's consider this StackOverflow's first page. This page will contain header (which will have used picture, names, etc), body, and footer. In the body, there is more profile data.
So, what you would be doing is creating a blade template, which will be saved as homepage.blade.php stored in "resources/views/layouts/homepage.blade.php".

```
@extend ('header_profile')
<body>
   <p>
        @yield('message)
   </p>
   <footer>
        End Page
   </footer>
 </body>
```

Now, create a controller homepage.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class CommunityController extends Controller {

    public function renderHomePage($user_id) {
        $userData = UserData::where('user_id', $user_id);
        $detailedUserData = DetailedUserInformation::where('user_id', $userData -> foreign_key_joiner);
        return view('homepage', ["main_info" => $userData, "personal_info" => $detailedUserData]);
    }

}
```

where "UserData" and "DetailedUserInformation" are eloquent models that are responsible for getting data from the database.

Now, what you gained was:

1. Creating models will help you use them again and again in different controllers. Thus, you will save writing the queries again and again.
2. Next, using blade template will help you create an HTML that does not break. In a case of appending again and again at the controller, one single tag might break everything. Hence, test once and use several times can be used.

Use this architecture. This will have better sustainability in long-term, and codes are reduced using the classes again and again.